# ERC1155 - Problem NFT Unidentified contract

Tags: solidity, erc-721, nft, openzeppelin, erc-1155

I'm trying to create an ERC1155 NFT but when I deploy the contract and try to see it on Opensea testnet, it always show "Unidentified contract" whereas I didn't have any problem with ERC721.

Here is the difference :
When you create an ERC721 you can add the name of the ERC721 token with its symbol like this :

```
contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

  constructor() ERC721 ("NAME", "SYMBOL") {
  }
```

However, this is completely different for ERC1155 tokens, this is my code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC1155, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC1155("JSON FILE WITH METADATA") {
        _mint(msg.sender,1,1,"");
    }
```

And this is what I have on my json file metadatas

```
{
   "name":"Sword",
   "description":"Sword from GameItems",
   "image":"link_picture"
}
```

By looking at this https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155#rationale
It seems that in order to put a name for the collection I have to insert it on the metadata itself, but I don't know which designation I have to use. I tried this:

```
{
   "title":"GameItems",
   "name":"Sword",
   "description":"Sword from GameItems",
   "image":"link_picture"
}
```

But it's not working. Did anyone succed in applying a name for the collection on Opensea ? It would be very helpful to have some advice

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a name and a symbol you can do the following:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC1155, Ownable {
    
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    
    constructor() ERC1155("JSON FILE WITH METADATA") {
        name = "Hello World 4321";
        symbol = "HELO";
        _mint(msg.sender,1,1,"");
    }
}
```

However if you want to define even more details about your collection and you only care about what people see on OpenSea. You could do something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC1155, Ownable {
    
    constructor() ERC1155("JSON FILE WITH METADATA") {
        _mint(msg.sender,1,1,"");
    }
    
    function contractURI() public view returns (string memory) {
        return "https://LINK-TO-COLLECTION-METADATA";
    }
}
```

And then upload another metadata file. **NOTE** this metadata file is not about the NFT its a seperate file about the collection.

```
{
  "name": "Hello World 4321",
  "description": "Welcome to my collection about Hello World 4321",
  "image": "https://link-to-image",
  "external_link": "https://link-to-website",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 100, # Indicates a 1% seller fee.
  "fee_recipient": "YOUR_ADDRESS_TO_COLLECT_ROYALTIES" 
}
```

I got this from [here](https://docs.opensea.io/docs/contract-level-metadata). You can also combine the code from both examples and do both :) Hope this helps!

P.S you didn't ask about it so maybe you have it covered. But I just want you to know that you might have an issue visualising your NFTs on OpenSea if you dont override the `uri()` function. Like [in this example](https://github.com/EatTheBlocks/nft-101/blob/main/final/contracts/SuperMarioWorldCollection.sol) I created for EatTheBlocks.

Comment: How to set them already for sale? Or, how to set the floor price for the collection?